# How a process running SQLite knows that a particular page has been updated by another process?

Tags: sqlite

How 2 independent SQLite cache modules get notified about the change in DB. More specifically, how the cache module know that a page has to be fetched from disk, as its content has been updated in DB by some other process.

Comment: So how SQLite in one process know that a particular cached page is dirty and the content has to be reread from the db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite writes all changed pages when a transaction finishes; once another connection is allowed to read, there are no dirty pages.

To detect changes made by other connections, there is the [file change counter](http://www.sqlite.org/fileformat2.html#file_change_counter) in the database header. However, it does not apply to specific pages but to the entire database.

Comment: There is some confusion. Let me clarify. Lets have one DB, with one table and table has only 2 rows. This info will pretty much will consume 1 or 2 pages. First process select * and will cache all the result in memory. Second connection also does select * and will have its own copy of cached pages. Now first connection updates 2 rows and it will update it cache and sync the data to db. And now if second connection does select * , it has the fresh data. SO my question is that what information helped second connection to identify that cached page is dirty.

Comment: This is not what "dirty" means. I've updated the answer.

Comment: After reading "file change counter", I assume that every read operation on any connection will first inspect file change counter byte, and then will decide whether to trust the cached pages, or simply invalidate the whole cache if byte value has changed. Can you please confirm my understanding so that I can up vote the answer. (Thanks a lot for all the clarification)

Comment: That's what I comprehended initially, but could not believe it that it will flush the whole cache even if only one row in entire db has been updated. But thanks a lot for clearing the doubt.